# UMVUE of $\exp(2 [\mu + \sigma^2])$ for $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, umvue

Suppose that $X_1, \ldots X_n$ are iid $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ where $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are both unknown with $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$, $\sigma \in \mathbb{R}+$, $\boldsymbol{\theta} = (\mu, \sigma)$, $n \geq 2$.  Consider the parametric function $\tau (\boldsymbol{\theta}) = e^{2(\mu + \sigma^2)}$.  Derive the UMVUE for $\tau(\theta)$.

Solution:

We can show $\boldsymbol{T} = (\bar{X}_n, S^2_n)$ is complete sufficient, where $\bar{X}_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n} X_i$ is the sample mean and $S^2_n = (n-1)^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i - \bar{X})^2$ is the sample variance.  I think best approach here is use $T = e^{2 X_1}$, so $E(T) = \tau(\theta)$, i.e., $T$ is unbiased.  Then by the Lehmann-Scheffe Theorem I ([link](https://fac.ksu.edu.sa/sites/default/files/marcel.dekker_-_probability.and_.statistical.inference.pdf), pg. 371), the UMVUE is
\begin{equation}
E_{\theta}[e^{2 X_1} | \bar{X}_n, S^2_n]
\end{equation}

Can we simplify this further?  Is there another approach to try?  Thanks.

Comment: Since mean and variance have different units, what does it mean to add them?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the comment.  Both the sample mean and sample variance are functions of the data.

Comment: Mean in meters, variance in meters squared. Mean in dollars, variance in dollars squared...

Comment: I added the formulas for the sample mean and sample variance.  You can add them directly.  Both are functions of the data.

Comment: There are inconsistencies in your question. The quantity you want to estimate in the title is different to the quantity stated in your question. Which is correct?

Comment: @Dave: since $\exp\{\mu+\sigma^2/2\}$ is the mean of a log-Normal $\mathcal{LN}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ variate, I do not see the issue in considering this quantity.

Comment: I've cleaned up the post.  The quantity $\tau(\theta)$ in the question was correct, the title was incorrect.  I also added the self-study tag.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105717.

Comment: @whuber, if I am following, it sounds like the Finney Function is the best hope to improve on my answer?